# Android - Conditional text value using Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to set the text of my TextView conditionally to either one or the other.

Android Data Binding documentation suggests that you can set the text conditionally if the text is a property of the view model. e.g.

```
android:text="@{user.displayName != null ? user.displayName : user.lastName}"
```

But is there any way to set the text from the strings.xml rather than adding it in my view model? I want something like this-

```
android:text="@{viewModel.expanded ? @string/collapse : @string/expand}"
```

The XML looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data class="TravellerInfoBinding">
      <import type="android.view.View" />
      <variable name="viewModel" type="com.myproject.viewmodel.TravellerInfoViewModel" />

   </data>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/expandable_arrow_blue" />

      <TextView style="@style/primary_pair_element_value" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@{viewModel.expanded ? @string/taxes_fees_detail : @string/hide_taxes_fees_detail}"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is my View Model-

```
package com.myproject.viewmodel;

imports...

public class TravellerInfoViewModel extends BaseObservable {

  @Bindable
  private final TaxDetailsViewModel taxDetailsViewModel;

  @Bindable
  private boolean expanded;

  Constructor....

  public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
  }

  public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.expanded);
  }

  public void toggleExpanded() {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  }

}
```

Comment: I thought that syntax worked. What problems are you encountering?

Comment: It is correct, have you got any error?

Comment: @CommonsWare Getting this compilation error `Error: Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. viewModel is missing it `

Comment: can you please post your xml file, something is missing in <data>

Comment: @RRR Thanks. Updated the question.

Comment: confirm your viewModel reference path as well as `expanded` is boolean or not.

Comment: @RRR Path is correct since Android Studio redirects me to the file from the XML. I've also added my view model in my question.

Comment: Can you add the DataBinding part of code within the activity ? Also, can you confirm that the package of TravellerInfoViewModel class is actually "com.myproject.viewmodel" or you have changed it to some placeholder while adding code snippet ?

Comment: I found the solution. It was my fault. I had one more method called `toggle() { expanded = !expanded; }` which when called wouldn't call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.expanded);` which is required. I don't know how to react. Apologies.

Comment: That should still not lead to that error. You should get a different one at runtime in which the values don't change.

Comment: @GeorgeMount You're right. That error was for missing import of Android View class. Which I figured out and edited the question later.

Answer (score 30):

Actually, this works fine for me

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
    style="@style/Common.Toolbar.Action.Text"
    android:onClickListener="@{onEditClick}"
    android:text="@{vm.editMode ? @string/contacts_done : @string/contacts_edit}"
    tools:text="@string/contacts_edit"/>
```

Where `vm` - it's a ViewModel and `editMode` - it's `ObservableBoolean`

Comment: How to achieve this using 2-way binding?

Comment: What do you mean - "2-way binding"?

Comment: Please refer to this link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: I still don't understand your question. The answer was about using resources with conditions. I don't understand how do you want to use two-way binding with resources

Comment: I wanted to ask if I make a change to the 'vm.editMode', how will the visibility be computed again. Is it possible?

Comment: As you can see in another answer - yes, it's possible to change visibility the same way (if this is what you want)

Comment: Needed to use @BindingMethods in my Fragment. But I'm working with ImageViews.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix/work-around :

1. define a duplicate Xml definition of the layout where you want a conditional value
2. for each block, set one of the condition values
3. set the visibility of each Xml definition according to the data binding boolean value

Not the ideal solution, not very pretty .. but functionally equivalent - and works in the interim until proper solution is found.

Here's how I solved it for `android:textStyle`, where I had a special case requirement for showing values in **bold**.

```
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.demo.app.SomeViewModel"/>

        ...

    <TextView
        style="@style/RowValue"
        android:visibility="@{ ! viewModel.boldRow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"
        />

    <TextView
        style="@style/RowValue"
        android:visibility="@{ viewModel.boldRow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        android:text="@{viewModel.currentValue}"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```